# Using apply() over columns to output subsets

Tags: r, subset, apply

I have a data frame in `R` where the majority of columns are values, but there is one character column. For each column excluding the character column I want to subset the values that are over a threshold and obtain the corresponding value in the character column.

I'm unable to find a built-in dataset that contains the pattern of data I want, so a `dput` of my data can be accessed [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=tiAs0aFi).

When I use subsetting, I get the output I'm expecting:

```
> df[abs(df$PA3) > 0.32,1]
[1] "SSI_01" "SSI_02" "SSI_04" "SSI_05" "SSI_06" "SSI_07" "SSI_08" "SSI_09"
```

When I try to iterate over the columns of the data frame using `apply`, I get a recursion error:

```
> apply(df[2:10], 2, function(x) df[abs(df[[x]])>0.32, 1])
 Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : 
  recursive indexing failed at level 2
```

Any suggestions where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your solution didn't work is that the `x` being passed to your user-defined function is actually a column of `df`. Therefore, you could get your solution working with a small modification (replacing `df[[x]]` with `x`):

```
apply(df[2:10], 2, function(x) df[abs(x)>0.32, 1])
```

You could use the `...` argument to `apply` to pass an extra argument. In this case, you would want to pass the first column:

```
apply(df[2:10], 2, function(x, y) y[abs(x) > 0.32], y=df[,1])
```

Comment: This works well, and each item in the resulting list is named after the column from which the values were extracted, which is extremely helpful.

Thanks for also explaining why my attempt at a solution didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another variation:

```
apply(abs(df[-1]) > .32, 2, subset, x=df[[1]])
```

The cute trick here is to "curry" subset by specifying the `x` parameter.  I was hoping I could do it with `[` but that doesn't deal with named parameters in the typical way because it is a primitive function :..(

Comment: I've also never seen this trick; there's always n+1 ways to skin a cat in `R`!

Answer (score 2):

A quick and non-sophisticated solution might be:

```
 sapply(2:10, function(x) df[abs(df[,x])>0.32, 1])
```

Comment: This works well, but the solution above which uses `apply` also gives sensible list item names, which is a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`lapply(df[,2:10],function(x) df[abs(x)>0.32, 1])`

Or using `apply`:

`apply(df[2:10], 2, function(x) df[abs(x)>0.32, 1])`